# Is deletion of an element faster in unsorted array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I read it somewhere that deletion of an element is faster in an unsorted array but I am not sure if that's correct.
According to my understanding if we want to delete some particular element then in the case of a sorted array it will take O(log N) time to search it and finally delete it but in the case of the unsorted array it may take in worst case O(N) time to search it linearly before we finally delete it.
So how is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

## Summarising all existing answers,

###### (And adding a few of my points)

There are `two` processes we need to consider when we delete an element from any array.

1. `Searching` for the element in consideration
2. `Deletion` of that element

*Note : In the below explanation, `n` is the total number of elements in the array.*

**Searching**

- In a `sorted array`, we can use `Binary Search` to find the array element to be deleted. The time complexity of Binary Search is `O(log n)`
- In an `unsorted array`, we must use `Linear Search` to find the array element to be deleted. The time complexity of Linear Search is `O(n)`

**Deletion**

The removal of an element from *any* array, is done with a time complexity of `O(1)`.

But the deletion process *also* includes what must be done *after* the removal of the element!

- In a `sorted array`, all the elements to the right of the deleted element must be shifted one index to the left, to fill the space left behind by the deleted element *and* to maintain sorted order. Therefore, the worst-case time complexity is `O(n)`
- In an `unsorted array`, we can fill the space left by the deleted element, with the last element in the array, since the array is unsorted *anyway*. The time complexity for this process is `O(1)`

### CONCLUSION :

**Sorted Array :**

- Searching : `O(log n)`
- Removal : `O(n)`

**Unsorted Array :**

- Searching : `O(n)`
- Removal : `O(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Deleting an element from an array is a `O(n)` operation if you physically remove that element from the array. That's because all the elements to the right of the deleted element must be shifted. It's only an `O(1)` operation if the element is at the end of the array so we can pop it.

Now, in an unsorted array you can just swap the found element with the element at the end of the array in `O(1)` and pop from the end one element, also in constant time.

But in a sorted array, if you want to keep it sorted, you can't do that. You have to physically remove the element to keep the array sorted.

So, to make it clear, you need explicitly say that removing an element from a sorted array and keeping it sorted is `O(n)`. If you don't care about it being sorted, you can remove it in `O(1)`. The searching is logarithmic, so this becomes logarithmic. But you can only do this once. Because after that the array isn't sorted anymore and you can't search for your element in log n time.

Comment: please read the full post, I have explained both these possibilities. You are just looking at the first paragraph.

Comment: Now that I reread my post, I see that you probably have misread the first paragraph. It says: `Deleting an element from an array is a O(n) operation **if** you physically remove that element from the array.` Then comes the part which you you quoted: `That's because all the elements to the right of the deleted element must be shifted. ` This is the explanation of the situation that came before. There is context that matters @greybeard

Comment: So what I feel you are trying to say is that if we just focus on the criteria of deleting an element and not focus on the searching pattern then it will just take constant time in case of unsorted array whereas it will take linear time in sorted array because of shifting of elements to keep it sorted. But if overall we consider deletion with search time then both will take linear time complexity . Am I right? @user1984

Comment: That's right. So in summary: searching in one is linear and in the other logarithmic. deleting in unsorted is constant while in sorted is linear, unless we are prepared to destroy the sorted property. This makes the combination of searching and deleting in both case linear, unless you search in a sorted array and remove in constant time (which you can do only once because it won't be sorted anymore).

Comment: @user1984 thank u so much.

Comment: You're welcome @AnanyaNayak please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer if you feel it helpful and/or answers your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Deletion of an element is faster in a sorted array than in an unsorted array.

This is because you can binary search over a sorted array to find the element specified.

An unsorted array has to check every single element one by one (linear search) to find the element to delete.

The delete operation itself is the same time complexity for both.

O(log N) takes *less* time to execute than O(N).

Answer (score 0):

Sorted array has an order that help us to find given element in O(logN) time. But in unsorted array we have no any order that can help us to find given element so each of the elements of array can be given element, so this enforce us to check all the elements in the array.

**Note that, lower bound finding an element in unsorted array is Ω(N), because we need check all the elements**

Also, because of Array is a static structure, so deletion or insertion is cost-full for us. So for delete in unsorted array you need at the first find it then remove it that has cost O(N).

For deletion in sorted array you can find it in O(logN) and then remove it that has cost O(logN). Note that in this approach, we doesn't shift element of array because this operation is expensive.